# Disk mount icons

Tags: mount

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and everything seems to be working fine, although there are two icons that won't go away in the task bar. They are labeled as rpool and bpool. The only option they give is to mount them. Although this will just bring up a error. what are these and how can I get rid of them or fix whatever is going on.

Comment: Did you install using zfs?

Comment: Yes I did. How would this affect the system? Or should I consider reinstalling and just use the standard encryption instead? I'm not particularly good with using Linux if that is of any indication for a decision.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove rpool and bpool SSD icons from Ubuntu 22.10 dock?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1440112/how-to-remove-rpool-and-bpool-ssd-icons-from-ubuntu-22-10-dock)