# How to remove rpool and bpool SSD icons from Ubuntu 22.10 dock?

Tags: 22.04, zfs, 22.10

[image: Question: How do I permanently get rid of the rpool and bpool SSD icons found in my Ubuntu dock?]

Question: How do I permanently get rid of the rpool and bpool SSD icons found in my Ubuntu dock?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just go to: `Settings > Appearance > Configure dock behavior`

Switch off: `Show volumes and devices`

[image: settings screenshot]

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a lifesavior!

Comment: You can hide only unmounted volumes, to remove safely and easily any pendrive